# How to unshorten this js code

Tags: javascript

I was trying to understand code of [this Tic-Tac-Toe (30 lines of code) game](http://jsfiddle.net/Kroid/XnV2E/2/) and encountered with this strange for me notation of js.

1. `t[id] ? ai() : move(id, 'ai');`
2. `!checkEnd() ? (role == 'player') ? ai() : null : reset()`

I know that this is shortened version of if-statement, but don't know exactly how to convert it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read up on the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) (AKA the conditional operator).

Comment: Got to love the arrogance of the comments... The second one is essentially a nested `if` statement. In case that was the confusing bit as you said you understand that it's a shorthand if statement.

Comment: I have already read that this is ternary operator, thanks, but how to translate second if-statement with function?

Comment: You'd evaluate the inner ternary first `(role == 'player') ? ai() : null` and the result becomes part of the outer ternary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) in javascript.

```
t[id] ? ai() : move(id, 'ai');
```

Translates to:

```
if (t[id])
    ai();
else
    move(id, 'ai');
```

And `!checkEnd() ? (role == 'player') ? ai() : null : reset()` to:

```
if (!checkEnd())
    if (role == 'player')
        ai();
    else
        ;
else
    reset();
```

Comment: thanks, and how second with function will be?

Comment: I will edit with that shortly, but I think you can deduce that from the first one

Comment: this second was confusing to me. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

That is called a ternary operator.

Check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) from MDN. They have good info if you're starting. 
And this one from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/be21c7hw%28VS.94%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Simply put,

```
condition ?  expression if true : expression if false
```